# How to get Garmin driver lib libGPSMap60CSx.so for QlandkarteGT on kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, kubuntu

I just updated from 14.04 to 16.04. When I now try to send data from QLandkarteGT to the Garmin device (GPSmap 60CSx) on kubuntu 16.04, it complains about missing shared library /usr/lib/qlandkartegt/libGPSMap60CSx.so

So there is no driver/plugin for the Garmin GPS device any more. This used to be part of package qlandkartegt-garmin in old release. According to package [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/q/qlandkartegt/qlandkartegt_1.8.1+ds-4/changelog), it seems this has been dropped  on purpose:

> qlandkartegt (1.8.1+ds-4) unstable; urgency=medium
>
> - Drop qlandkartegt-garmin from Recommends.
>     Lacks support for libusb 1.0 and is no longer developed upstream.
> - Update Repository URLs for move to Bitbucket in upstream metadata.
>
> -- Bas Couwenberg   Fri, 08 Jan 2016 20:15:18 +0100

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on german ubuntu users [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/QLandkarteGT/). It references a PPA that provides the package qlandkartegt-garmin:

ppa:dirk-computer42/c42-backport

After adding this PPA and installing qlandkartegt-garmin from it, my GPSmap device can be used in qlandkartegt again.